# application crashing while running navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am a beginner in android, and I tried to make a `Navigation Drawer` by following tutorials. But I got an error here, please help me to continue further

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout), toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.navigate) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.kitty.emo.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private Boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private Boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private View containerView;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}


public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");


            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
    }
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}

public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String prefernceName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(prefernceName, defaultValue);
}

}
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.kitty.emo.NavigationDrawerFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and last 
logcat:

```
06-05 14:20:11.806  13896-13896/com.example.kitty.emo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kitty.emo, PID: 13896
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kitty.emo/com.example.kitty.emo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kitty.emo.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:79)
        at com.example.kitty.emo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check line number 79 in `NavigationDrawerFragment.java`

Comment: What is on line 79 at navigation drawer fragment?

Comment: I assume getActivity() is null at this point.